# how to properly disable auto-completion when doing macro expansion

Tags: emacs, macros, evil-mode

I'm looking for a way to temporarily disable auto-completion frameworks (`corfu` in my case) when I'm doing macro-expansion. the problem is that when I'm running a `kbd-macro`, or trying to insert to multiple lines in `evil-visual-line`, auto completion gets triggered, this corrupts my insertion and makes macros run very slow.

I already tried using advice around the `kmacro-end-or-call-macro` like this:

```lisp
(defun my-marco-advice-deactivate-some-modes (fn &rest args)
    (corfu-mode -1) (apply fn args) (corfu-mode 1))

(advice-add #'kmacro-end-or-call-macro :around #'my-marco-advice-deactivate-some-modes)
```

the problem here is when I use `C-g` to quit the macro `corfu-mode` will be disabled afterward and I have to re-enable again.

in the case of `evil-visual-line` I couldn't figure out a way to disable `corfu-mode` as pressing
`I` runs `evil-insert`.

is there a more general way to solve this problem as I think both `kmacro-end-or-call-macro` and visual-line insertion use `macro-expansion` ?

Comment: try wrapping `(apply fn args)` in a `condition-case` to handle a quit and maybe errors as well, eg. `(condition-case-unless-debug err (progn (corfu-mode -1) (apply fn args) (corfu-mode 1)) (error (message "some error: %s" (error-message-string err)) (corfu-mode 1)) (quit (corfu-mode 1)))`.  I dont have corfu to test it out.  If `corfu` uses a `pre-command-hook`, you might be able to remove that temporarily instead of disabling the mode, not sure

Comment: I used `unwind-protect` with the advice, works so far. but still can't get it to work with `evil-visual-line` or macro expansions.